# Aptos sdk transaction_argument

Tags: python, blockchain, contract, aptos

I have made a bot in python for minting, but there is one problem. When I'm sending args in payload for contract, It's sending this:
[image]

But when I do a manual mint, arguments are in string and not bytes¨

[image]

I'm using aptos_sdk

[image]

Comment: I'll look into this. For now, could you please alter your question to have code as text instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
payload = EntryFunction.natural(
                f"{mint_address}::candy_machine_v2",
                "mint_tokens",
                [],
                transaction_arguments,
            )
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).